# How to search Zero Width Joiner (ZWJ in SQL Server - unicode 200d)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

[image: Here I am attaching screen shot of that]

Below query condition doesn't work

For eg :

```
SELECT * FROM NAME WHERE (NAME_MA LIKE N'%‍%')
```

Comment: Try NAME_MA LIKE N'%‍' + NCHAR(0x200d) + '%'

Comment: It is returning everything , bad luck of mine.

Comment: Searching for it with `CHARINDEX` return the position? In that case the query can be changed to `WHERE CHARINDEX(...) > 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM NAME WHERE HEX(NAME_MA) LIKE '%‍E2808D%')
```

E2808D is Hex representation for ZWJ character.
Similarly you can use E2808C for ZWNJ character if you are interested.